# Why is my SpaCy v3 scorer returing 0 for precision, recall and f1?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, precision-recall, spacy-3

I have the following code (migration from SpaCy v2) where I would like to calculate the precision, recall and f1-score for a given model:

```
nlp = spacy.load("my_model")
scorer = Scorer(nlp)
examples = []
for text, annotations in TEST_DATA:
    examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations))
results = scorer.score(examples)
print(
    "Precision {:0.4f}\tRecall {:0.4f}\tF-score {:0.4f}".format(results['ents_p'], results['ents_r'], results['ents_f'])
)
```

The weird thing I try to understand is why it always returns

```
Precision 0.0000    Recall 0.0000   F-score 0.0000
```

My TEST_DATA set is in the same form as the TRAIN_DATA set I was using to train the same model. Here is how it looks like:

```
[
    (
        'Line 106 – for dilution times, the units should be specified', {'entities': [(51, 60, 'ACTION'), (41, 47, 'MODAL'), (11, 40, 'CONTENT'), (0, 8, 'LOCATION')]}
    ),
    (
        'It should be indicated what test was applied  to verify the normality of distribution.', {'entities': [(13, 22, 'ACTION'), (28, 85, 'CONTENT'), (3, 9, 'MODAL')]}
    )
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scorer does not run the pipeline on the predicted docs, so you're evaluating blank docs against your test cases.

The recommended way is to use `nlp.evaluate` instead:

```py
scores = nlp.evaluate(examples)
```

If you want the call the scorer directly for some reason, the other alternative is to run the pipeline on the predicted docs (`nlp` instead of `nlp.make_doc`), so:

```py
example = Example.from_dict(nlp(text), annots)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this works now :)
A side question, is there a way to divide the scores per LABAL, so have one score set per LABEL?

Comment: Look at `ents_per_type`?

Comment: Thanks, all good now. Really appreciate your help